# Android app reloads on resume

Tags: android, webview

I'm writing an Android app, which starts a broadcast receiver checking the network existence and in case it exists the app loads a local HTML file into WebView. Then from the HTML file works the JavaScript code, which makes an AJAX request and generates the layout based on the response (XML file). Everything works fine besides one thing.

If the app is running (in foreground) and the screen goes to sleep mode (lights off), then clicking the power button turns on screen and everything works fine. But when the screen is appox. 1.5 hours in a sleep mode, then clicking the power button turns on screen, but also reloads my app. I don't want my app to be reloaded. I didn't see the same with other apps (e.g. Facebook, What's up, etc).

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Is there some directive in the manifest I can make to make it do this? So I don't want it to restart the app when coming back into the app from a pause.

Answer (score 2):

Android may destroy your activity or even the process if user doesn't use it for extended period of time. (Exact behavior differs between devices)
So you need (at least) to properly save all important state in your `onSaveInstanceState` Activity method and pick it up in `onCreate` or `onRestoreInstanceState`. "properly" means using a persistent storage. If you don't mind device restarts, then you can use provided `Bundle` object; otherwise, use SharedPreferences, SQLite DB or write data to a file by yourself... good luck!

### Update

If you want to present the same Activity after Android "forgets" where was the user last time, you will need to arrange it explicitly... for example, you may save something (as written above) and in your startup activity use it to trigger starting of corresponding activity.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know about the bundles you mentioned, but how can I save the state of WebView, i.e. the content (rendered HTML/JS, etc)? And the second question is, how it works in, for example, Facebook app?

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan I'm only guessing, but you can try to get its state via [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState%28%29) (which, by the way, Android uses automatically when it thinks that View state must be saved)

Comment: Sarge Borch  I'll try it, thanks! One more question. Do you know, or is there any documentation where it says how much is that "extended period of time"? Or maybe there are other factors too, apart from time.

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan I am 95% sure that it is adjusted by firmware authors every time, so it's a sort of "implementation defined" thing. You'd better not rely on it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

All background tasks should be don by service.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

You should also consider to use AlarmManager to preserve battery:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

I don't know if it will be possible with this fancy Cordova (?) design.

Comment: @piotro thanks for your answer. Which kind of background tasks do you mean? My app is running as a foreground task. What should I do in service if I'll create it? By the way, I'm not using Cordova (or something like that).

Comment: I.e some data refreshing. You should have all your data downloaded in native part, then onResume download it to view from cache. Alternative - you can override the onSavedInstanceState() of Activity.